# Drive API update

Tags: google-drive-api

We got the Drive API update changes last week.

The email content:

[image]

Very appreciate if you can help to confirm the following two questions:

1. We have tried the `resourceKey`, but it didn't work, is there a specific time for it to take effect?
2. 

> URL type fields such as exportLinks, webContentLink, and webViewLink
> will include the resourceKey.

Currently, we are just using the `webViewLink`, do we still need to update our code for accessing files to include the appropriate resource keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning Monday, September 13, 2021, Google will begin enforcing a security update to Google Drive. Users like you who own or manage impacted files will be notified about the affected files beginning Monday, July 26, 2021.

This security update adds a resource key that makes sharing links from Google Drive files more secure. When file links are updated, users may receive new file access requests. Those who do not have accessed to the files before the update will have to use URLs containing resource keys to access the files.

To avoid broken links, users should update Google Drive links on their websites and shared resources before September 13.

## Update Impacts Developers

Affected items are those that have a Drive File API permission with type=domain or `type=anyone` where `withLink=true` [(v2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions) or `allowFileDiscovery=false` [(v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).

In addition to the item ID, applications may need a resource key to access files. Use [Google’s Developer resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys) to learn more about how this update will impact your projects.

## access

You can also check that the resourceKey security update is already activated in your domain by going to Google Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The effects should have kicked in today, the 13th.  So far I'm NOT getting the resourceKey when I call for a file list.  Yes, the resourceKey is part of the field list I send.  Testing this in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get using * for field list and a file ID that SHOULD be returning a resourceKey there is nothing returned for resourceKey.  We are getting 403 errors on certain operation in our code - only place where a direct URL to the Google drive is used.

Essentially we do NOT have the resourceKey supplied to us so there is no way to add it to the URL!

When I checked my test GDrive before the weekend in order to turn this security update ON, the console indicated that it was already turned on, which I had certainly not done!