# Required Drive API update

Tags: google-drive-api

Like other users I received an email from google in which I have to update my code before 13th. I've read other threads but I'm still confused because there are not many answers about that...

I have I script which I use but it was created by other colleague and I don't know what tod do, I have no idea... So, this is the email

> What do I need to know?

> Items that have a Drive API permission with type=domain or type=anyone, where withLink=true (v2) or allowFileDiscovery=false (v3), will be affected by this security update.

> In addition to the item ID, your application may now also need a resource key to access these items. Without a resource key, requests for these items may result in a 404 Not Found error (See below for details). Note that access to items that are directly shared with the user or group are not affected.

> Will this change affect me?

> If your application uses the Drive API to access files which have been shared with a user through link sharing, your application may be affected by this change.

> What do I need to do?

> To avoid errors accessing files, you must update your code for accessing files to include the appropriate resource keys. Details on how to do this for each of the affected Drive APIs is included below:

> Changes to the Drive API

> The resource key of an item is returned on the resourceKey field of the file metadata in the Drive API response.

> If the file is a shortcut file, then the resource key for the target of the shortcut can be read from the shortcutDetails.targetResourceKey field of the same resource.
> URL type fields such as exportLinks, webContentLink, and webViewLink will include the resourceKey.

> Requests to the Drive API can specify one or more resource keys with the X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys HTTP request header.

> Changes to Apps Script

> The DriveApp from Apps Script has been updated to return the resource key of a file or folder with the getResourceKey method.

> Note: When fetching a file or folder, the resource key can be specified on the getFileByIdAndResourceKey or getFolderByIdAndResourceKey methods.

> Changes to Drive UI Integrations

> If your application is integrated with the Drive UI to create or open items, it will receive resource keys when your application is invoked from the Drive UI.

> The state information for a New URL will contain folderResourceKey, which is the resource key of the folder where the new item should be created.

> The state for an Open URL will contain a mapping of file ID to resource key in the resourceKeys field.

> Which projects may be affected?

> Your projects that have used the Drive API in the last 30 days and may be affected by this change are below: Script Recogida Datos Cognitiv (project-id-2193222022860412188)

Could anyone tell me what should I do?, because I don't know where to start.

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drive API update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916253/drive-api-update)

Comment: Thankyou  @ziganotschka, I'll take a look to that thread

Comment: After reading the thread suggested by the user, I still don't know what to do to update with the info Google says. Anyone who have already applied these changes could help? Thank you :)